# how to make input field border red color while sending empty value using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, my objective is to show border in red color when we click on send button without entering any value in input text field. I don't know how to get border red in material-ui. Do i need to validate the input field? If yes then do i need to validate with letters and alphanumeric regex? I'm bit confused in here.

Here is the code:

```
 <TextField
            margin="dense"
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
            placeholder="Enter a Message"
            name="msg"
            id="text"
          />
          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send</Button>
```

Can anyone assist me in this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a value property in TextField and after submitting check value property is empty or not if empty then add a dynamic class in TextField.

```
state = { msg: "" }
```

Add an onChange and classname inside TextField attribute.

```
onChange = e => this.setState({ msg: e.target.value })
classname={this.state.msg !== "" ? "borderRed":""}
```

Comment: hi, after adding value property i couldn't enter any value

Comment: Let me know if it helps or not.